# Start a PHP server on Mac OS X

Tags: php, macos, server

I am figuring out how to use [PHP OpenId](https://github.com/openid/php-openid)

I have cloned the repo to the `~/www` directory. There are some examples in the `php-open-id/examples` directory which I wanted to run.

Specifically, I wanted to render the page `php-open-id/examples/consumer/index.php` in order to better understand the API. I started a server in the `php-open-id/examples` directory using

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

and I navigated to `localhost://consumer/index.php`

But it didn't work. It shows a dialog box to save the file. What is the correct way to render this PHP file?

Comment: Why do you run a Python server for ap PHP application?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

I have found  a solution :

Run the server using

```
php -S localhost:9000
```

Comment: Amen! No need for NGINX here

Answer (score 12):

Mac OS

Just Visit your project folder

open terminal on that folder

and Run  `php -S localhost:9000`

then you can see

```
PHP 7.3.24-(to be removed in future macOS) Development Server started at Tue Mar 30 11:58:49 2021
Listening on http://localhost:9000
```

After that you are able to access your application on  http://localhost:9000
if your port is not available  try to change port

Comment: Please share more details. Is there any good reason to duplicate an answer that is six years older than yours?

Comment: details  were missing like from where to run cmd

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a php server for serving .php files. The simple python server is not a php server and therefore it is just simply listing the files in the directory for download.

If you are on OSX 10 or above, it comes with apache which has php module present and can be setup to serve php file.

Tutorials can be found here 
http://php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.bundled.php and here https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3083

If you would like to setup a dedicated server instead of using apache, MAMP is a good solution. Google It and see tutorials on how to set it up.

Comment: The A in MAMP stands for Apache. It isn't an alternative to Apache, it just bundles Apache with some other software.

Comment: "Tutorials can be found here" - please don't post answers that solely link to any external ressource

Answer (score -2):

Update November 2022:

Unfortunately, PHP has been removed from MacOS. This is a [brief tutorial](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250006086) which explains how to get PHP working in Ventura.

I personally dislike the idea to compensate the lack of PHP with the activities outlined in the tutorial. My solution was to install Docker and to run a proper NGINX+PHP container. I consider it to be cleaner, more flexible and better to maintain rather than faffing about with half-baked on-board stuff. But that's a matter of taste, I guess.

Also, as suggested in one of the answers, using the Python approach is not hassle free in Ventura, since it requires xcode to be installed.

In MacOS 10.x I have also been working with the on-board Python and PHP. Having lost those tools as standard installations is annoying.

Comment: "compensate the lack of PHP with Apache" - that's not possible. Apache itself won't run any PHP code

Comment: The brief tutorial explains how to get a webserver working, but "Doing the same for PHP is left as an exercise for the reader."